# Maria DB limiting root user privileges

Tags: mariadb, permissions

I am logged in as the `root` user in Maria DB and I cannot grant view access to a service account user.
[image]

Can anyone explain a cause or suggest a fix?

Comment: Indeed we have more than two `root` users with different hosts. Thank you for your insight.